# user_validation function is not invoked in Home controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to validate a user form, which I am trying to submit after taking the input in view named as 'home.php', where I have specified the `base_url('Home/user_validation')`.

With `Home` is name of the controller and `user_validation` is the method name. I tried to figure out the issue but I could not understand why not any other function is being invoked apart from index function in Home controller. Please help me in this case.

**Controller Home.php**

```
public function user_validation()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Invalid username and password.');
        redirect('home');
    }
    else {
        $user_name123 = $this->input->post('username');
        $teacher = $this->input->post('remember');

        if ($user_name123 == 'admin') {
            $query = $this->login_model->validate();
            echo("Logged in");
        }
    }
}
```

**Model login_model.php**

```
function validate()
{
    $this->db->where('admin_username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('admin_password', $this->input->post('password'));
    $this->db->where('active_status', 'Yes');
    $query = $this->db->get('cis_tbl_admin');

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**View  home.php**

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('Home/user_validation') ?>" method="post" id="instantform">
<fieldset>
    <div class="input-prepend" title="Username" data-rel="tooltip">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
        <input autofocus class="input-large span10"
               name="username" id="username" type="text"
               placeholder="user name"/>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="input-prepend" title="Password" data-rel="tooltip">
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
        <input class="input-large span10" name="password"
               id="password" type="password"
               placeholder="password" autocomplete="off"/>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <div class="input-prepend">
        <label class="remember" for="remember">
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember"
                   value="teacher"/>Teacher Login</label>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    <p class="center span5">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        <br/><br/>
        <!--<a class="ajax-link" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>parent_info/get_students_info"> <span class="hidden-tablet">Parent Login</span></a>-->
    </p>
</fieldset>

<input type="hidden" name="sys_date" id="sys_date" value="<?php echo $sys_date; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="sys_time" id="sys_time" value="<?php echo $sys_time; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="details" id="details" value="<?php echo $details; ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: pass parameters to validate Function

Comment: have u load the url helper

Comment: there are may be some typo mistake in form action,do you check using base_url('home/user_validation') in form action. Also This should be defined in route.php.

Comment: I hope you are hashing your password? With something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and to verify it http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php to me it looks like your storing plain passwords. Also don't use sha1 or md5 for passwords

Answer (score 0):

Check your config routes file to be sure you call functions of the home controller:

```
$route['Home/(:any)'] = 'Home/$1';
```